# send data from jquery dialog to parent page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have used jquery ui dialog using IFrame and passed URL to that IFrame. So new page opened in dialog box in Iframe.

After some processing in that dialog box page. I want to pass some data from that dialog box to my page on close event.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it is the only solution, but you can write the data you want to pass to some invisible element in the close event of the dialog.

Example:

```
$("..").dialog({...}).bind('dialogclose',function(){
          $("#someInvisibleElement").val(data);
});
```

Comment: Can you please give example for above syntax.. dialog({...})

Comment: Yes, close if fired but how can I get content from dialog box in my main page?

Comment: Its done. var value = $("#pgiFrame").contents().find("#spdata").html();

Answer (score 0):

To access the parent page on an iframe you can use window.parent

Comment: Yes, but how and where to write that function. When I click on my custom button on my page to close jquery dialog then its working fine but when I click close CROSS sign then it is not calling that function.